# wildcard search for a particular word "not followed" by a specific string, not working

Tags: microsoft-word, search, wildcards

I have a document with hundreds of occurrences of the Spanish equivalent of "US$ million", which is "millones de dólares EE.UU.", and I want to make sure I have not left out any part of it, i.e., it is too easy to just write "millones de dólares" (omitting the "EE.UU." part) or even just "millones" and move on, leaving out the "dólares de EE.UU."

I thought this would be straightforward, but my wildcard search is not working.

I am trying this search, with wildcards:

(millones) [!(de dólares EE.UU.)]

It does not find any wrong strings. I have tried using backslashes before the periods, and removing the first set of parenth, all to no avail.

Below is the test passage that I am using, which contains four wrong instances of my target sequence. I want my search to find all four of these wrong patterns.

En 2015, el 44,4% de los compromisos de ayuda para el comercio fue para Asia, que recibió 23.900 millones de dólares E.UU., es decir, 4.900 millones dólares EE.UU. más que en 2014. Aunque las cantidades destinadas a Asia Meridional y Central se redujeron en 1.200 millones EE.UU., las destinadas al Lejano Oriente aumentaron en 5.100 millones de dólares debido, principalmente, a importantes compromisos destinados a Indonesia (energía) y Filipinas (transporte y almacenamiento).

To make things stranger, after much trial and error I found that another search (below) does find *one* of the wrong strings (the third instance, "millones EE.UU."), but not the second ("millones dólares EE.UU."):

(millones) [!(de dólares)]   with wildcards

What am I missing?!

Thank you very much to whoever can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exclamation mark (!) works in a different way. You cannot exclude a word using it but only a single character from provided list of characters. See more: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

I don't think you can solve this problem with a single regex search in Word. I would use a workaround here. First copy your file and work on a copy. Search (in a copy) for full correct expression: "millones de dólares EE.UU." and replace it with nothing (remove it). Then search for "millon" and consider if your findings should be corrected in the original file.